# Error while using Monitor class in WinForms. Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

A Win Form App that uses System.Threading. Two threads threadA and threadB are started with the same method sumNumber. 
sumNumber updates a variable **total**. so these two threads try to update the same variable.

Using the monitor class to synchronize the access to the **total** variable.

Getting a Runtime Exception of "**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException**' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication2.exe

Additional information: **Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code**.

How do I properly use the Monitor class in this.

```
 int total;

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            total = 0;

            Thread threadA;
            Thread threadB;

            threadA = new Thread(sumNumber);
            threadA.Start();
            threadB = new Thread(sumNumber);
            threadB.Start();

            threadA.Join();
            threadB.Join();

            listBox1.Items.Add("Total is: " + total);
        }

        public void sumNumber()
        { 
            long numRepeats = 100000;

            for (int i = 0; i < numRepeats; i++)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(total);
                total = total + 10;
                Monitor.Exit(total);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object you passed to Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit must be the same. Since the value of total changes, Monitor.Exit tries to exit but there isn't any corresponding Monitor.Enter with the same object, thus throwing the Exception

You should have

`private readonly object TotalLock = new object();`

as a member variable, then

```
Monitor.Enter(TotalLock);
total = total + 10;
Monitor.Exit(TotalLock);
```

which can be shortened as

```
lock (TotalLock)
{
    total = total + 10;
}
```

Comment: So Monitor object can only be used on reference types and not on primitive data types.

Comment: The method signature is `public static void Enter(object obj)`, so if you pass in a value type, it'll get boxed and everything breaks